# Why does computer restarts by itself

Tags: hardware-failure, reboot

I'll like to use the question progressively: (I need to pin point exact issue)
My system configuration is:

```
CPU: Intel i7 2600K 3.4GHz Quad core
Motherboard: z68
RAM: GSkill 8GB saw-tooth 1.5V
Graphics card: ATI Radeon HD6870
HDD 2TB SATA
Power Supply: 750W (Antec Gold series)
```

I built this machine for gaming and nothing is under/over clocked, it runs awesome as long as it runs i.e.

Issue:
While playing game computer would start making really loud scratching noises (doesn't matter what speaker level is at) and picture would distort and machine used to hang. So I replaced my video card and shifted RAMs from 2 different channels to single channel.

I've not seen scratching noise/ hang since then (maybe once/twice but not everytime).

However even now after playing for a while computer restarts by itself, why would it be?

Here are few scenarios I'm considering:

1. Overheating (Tried BIOS immediately after restart and CPU temperature was around 50-60 degree Celsius everytime so I'm not sure)
2. Use of SATA HDD -- really ?? can it be possible
3. GPU/RAM overheating.
4. Something entirely different.

I would like to pin point the reason first and then need to find an answer.

I've Windows7 installed and Ubuntu 11.10 issue is observed in both cases.

Comment: Out of your list only 1 and 3 are likely.  Although the fact you went from dual channel to a single channel and it resolve the problems for the most part seem odd.

Comment: I don't understand why is it flagged for "not enough research" when I clearly stated > "I would like to pin point the reason first and then need to find an answer." Anyways if this makes anyone happier I was following http://windowsforums.org/topic/7298-computer-restarts-by-itself/ and I didn't want people to start their answers based off on that discussion

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86

Comment: Boot from a [memtest86](http://memtest.org) CD and let it run for a few hours.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes I'm still hoping overheating is only the issue -- I can simply add cooling system but couldn't understand the RAM issue.

Comment: @Aki and DavidSchwartz: Can you please let me know how much is few hrs? I've tried memtest which come prebundled with Ubuntu and let it run for around 4 hrs without any warning/error. Thanks though I'll run memtest once again overnight and see the results in morning (hopefully computer won't turn off :P )

Comment: I've got the AMD Athlon 64 4000+ with 4GB of DDR2 (800Mhz). A single loop takes about an hour.

Comment: @Aki: Ok I'll run it overnight tonight, Thanks :) will reply with results

Comment: You can run [Real Temp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) with the alarm sound on. It can monitor both CPU and GPU temperature. Also what do you mean by "loud scratching noises"? Can you tell where it came from? If it's not from the sound card, it could be the fans, hdd or even the power supply.

Comment: You definitely want to add the power supply as a possible cause, they can even make your room lights flicker. It could be either broken or could provide not enough power for your new video card. *Don't question me, it's personal experience...* :(

Comment: @TomWijsman: added power supply thanks for suggestion

Comment: @billc.cn: The sound is definitely from sound card (the one with Radeon HD6870 connected to monitor with built in speakers through HDMI cable), And I'm not sure how to describe the sound itself -- consider sound of chalk on black board just amplify it and increase the pitch. Thanks for real temp I'll try it

Comment: The sound suggests that something is oscillating.  Power supply would be the first suspect, but just about any component that draws much power could do it.

Comment: Check the bios for the temp that it'll shutdown the computer at when it gets too warm.  I'd say this is your problem.  Really you should try to improve airflow.  Make sure the fans are not set to run too low in the BIOS.  Or, get an extra fan.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a video card issue considering it happens under games. Is it only under games?

I'd check your driver settings. I know the AMD cards sometimes do this when Catalyst AI is enabled (which is the default). I'd disable Catalyst AI.  Then turn off AMD Overdrive and fire up your game and see what happens.

Comment: I've installed drivers for radeon (hence Catalyst) but never looked at any settings, first thing I'll check is Catalyst AI then run a game for a while and then will try all other suggestions.

Comment: @bill.cn I've set Catalyst A.I. to performance (instead of quality) and Started Real Temp to monitor the temperature as well. I couldn't find GPU temperature but this is helpful enough will test it overnight and let u guys know

Comment: Tried it y'day and game worked great for around 3 and half hr will try longer over weekend :)

Comment: @bill.cn: temperatures seem to be well withing threshold thanks for the program I'll keep monitoring the temperature